# Randomize dynamic content blocks

Tags: marketing-cloud, dynamic, email-studio

I have one dynamic content block that is filtered off a field in a data extension, but another that I want to be a random selection of 2 options.
Sort of an A/B test, if you will.

Is there a way to support this without having to do some kind of filtering based on `subscriber_key` or `email_address` starting with 'a-l' and 'm-z'?

The desire is for it to be truly randomized (but with a 50/50 split).

Comment: Can you utilize the A/B content block? This sounds like a perfect use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create two data extensions from the Source DE, and use ampscript (or Dynamic content) to serve the content.

i.e

```
/* First 50% call this DE1 */ 

SELECT TOP (50) PERCENT
Column1
,Column2
,Column3
, Content1 AS Content

FROM SourceDE

/* Save this as DE 2 */
SELECT 
Column1
,Coulmn2
,Column3
,Content2  AS Content

FROM SourceDE s
LEFT JOIN DE1 d
ON s.Column1 = d.Column1

WHERE d.Column1 IS NULL
```

Place these two queries in an automation and set it to overwrite.

I would then use DE1 and DE2 in my sends ,

Using the logic in this pseudo code:

```
if Content == Content1, Send Variation A
If Content == Content 2 , Send Variation B
```

Comment: The source data extension is not a static group but grows everyday.  It's a welcome journey.  
Your solution would require two journey's with a similar path, no?

Comment: If you refresh the automation every day then it would take a random 50% of the entire population. Have you looked at Random Splits if you are using Journey Builder?