# Show dynamic content based on percentage

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions, dynamic-content

I want to show a certain contentblock randomized to new subscribers. We want to ask them to leave a review on a certain website (or websites).

Though, some review websites are more important than others, so the distribution isn't 25%/25%/25%/25%, but rather something like 40%/25%/15%/10%/5%/5%.

Our entry DE is populated through an automation on a daily base, I'd like to have a column updated as soon as they are inserted in the entry DE. Once entered in the entry DE they would be inserted in the journey. Based on the new column I'd like to show content (based on dynamic content or ampscript -> ContentByContentID).

So e.g. subscriber 1 enters the entry DE. Column "review" is updated to Website1
Suscriber 2 enters the entry DE. Column "review" is updated to Website1
.. Website2
.. Website3

Etc etc. It doesn't need to rotate on every subscriber, but in the long run I'd like to see a distribution that looks like (e.g.) as 40/25/15/10/...

What is the best way to do something like this?

I found this; but this is based on a static list. Our lists grows everyday.

[Randomize dynamic content blocks](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/207043/randomize-dynamic-content-blocks)

Thanks,

Comment: Hi Geert, do you have control over the Automation that populates the DE each day? Could you add an extra column into this DE? I can help/provide an answer based on this information.

Answer (score 4):

You could assign the groups with a Query Activity.  I validated this in my local SQL Server.

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN x.RowNum * 1.00 / x.Cnt <= 0.05 THEN 'A'
        WHEN x.RowNum * 1.00 / x.Cnt <= 0.15 THEN 'B'
        WHEN x.RowNum * 1.00 / x.Cnt <= 0.30 THEN 'C'
        WHEN x.RowNum * 1.00 / x.Cnt <= 0.55 THEN 'D'
        else 'E'
    END Grp
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        s.*
        , row_number() over(order by newid()) as RowNum
        , count(*) over() AS Cnt
    FROM YOUR_SOURCE_DE s
) x
```

[image: validation query]

[image: math]

**NOTE**: I used a `select s.*` in my inner query for simplicity.  I would definitely include all of the columns in your actual query.

**Credit**: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20273593/812377

Comment: Just a note, depending on audience size on each run, there will be a margin of error on this (as well as all percentage calculations) but it should be significantly lower than using something like NTILE() etc. So if you see the divide shows something like 46% | 24% | 17% | 9% | 4% - know that it is 'expected' behavior due to the multiple runs on varying audience size.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [Random Split](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_split_journey_contacts_at_random.htm&type=5) activity at the start of your journey to split the new subscribers into the weighted options your require; 40%/25%/15%/10%/5%/5% etc..
After the Split, you then use the [Update Contact](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_update_a_contact.htm&type=5) activity to "set" a value for each path.

For example, the 40% path Update Contact activity would update [Review] to "Website1", the 25% path would update to "Website2", and so on.

[image: Journey Split EG]

In your email, you can then use [LookupRows](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/lookuprows.htm) in AMPScript to lookup what the "Review" value is, and show the correct content based on this value.

However, Journey Builder's Random Split function has a hard limit of 10 paths. If you need more than 10 "random" segments, you could pre-generate the random number in your SQL activity using the [RAND()](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_rand.asp) function. [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45819307/can-you-use-random-numbers-in-a-case-statement-sql-server-2016) shows how it can be achieved in-line in SQL.

If doing it all in SQL is too hard, you could also put the RAND() value into your [Review] column, and use the LookupRows function to retrieve the value in your email, and do the IF Statement in your email.

Both of these solutions will keep the random value you assigned each customer, so you can do post-campaign reporting on the outcomes.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a different way when it doesn't matter which customer gets which link. (even can be different any time).

I would use a journey with that dataextension and create a random split that you can define. Like 40% go path 1, 25% path 2, 15% path3, 10% path 4, 10% path 5. Each path would then have a different contentBlock in that area. Then you would have 5 different Newsletters that do not have that dynamic block (but maybe others).

This would be a kind of easy way to accomplish what you want without other sql activities etc.